# Coursera Not Accepting Reasonably correct code

Tags: deep-learning

Coursera is not passing this IoU code as correct although it is giving correct results. Please help

## GRADED FUNCTION: iou

def iou(box1, box2):
    """Implement the intersection over union (IoU) between box1 and box2

```
Arguments:
box1 -- first box, list object with coordinates (x1, y1, x2, y2)
box2 -- second box, list object with coordinates (x1, y1, x2, y2)
"""

# Calculate the (y1, x1, y2, x2) coordinates of the intersection of box1 and box2. Calculate its Area.
### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 5 lines)
xi1 = np.max([box1[0], box2[0]])
yi1 = np.max([box1[1], box2[1]])
xi2 = np.min([box1[2], box2[2]])
yi2 = np.min([box1[3], box2[3]])
inter_area = (yi2 - yi1) * (xi2 - xi1)
### END CODE HERE ###    

# Calculate the Union area by using Formula: Union(A,B) = A + B - Inter(A,B)
### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 3 lines)
box1_area = max(box1[3] - box1[1],0) * max(box1[2] - box1[0],0)
box2_area = max(box2[3] - box2[1],0) * max(box2[2] - box2[0],0)
union_area = box1_area + box2_area - inter_area
### END CODE HERE ###

# compute the IoU
### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line)
iou = inter_area / union_area
### END CODE HERE ###

return iou
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to compute the intersection area, you need to make sure the height and width of the intersection are positive, otherwise the intersection area should be zero. Use max(height, 0) and max(width, 0).
you need to change your code as 
 inter_area = max((xi2-xi1),0) * max((yi2-yi1),0)

Answer (score 0):

```
AssertionError: Intersection must be 0
```

For this error, you may need to change the code to

```
inter_width = max((xi2-xi1),0)
inter_height = max((yi2-yi1),0)
inter_area = inter_width * inter_height
```